# Do request to Eureka client using server

Tags: netflix-eureka

I hava eureka server at `eureka-server.com` host and application with appId `facade` registered at server. Facade application has `/users` endpoint. Can I call `/users` endpoint through Eureka server something like this `eureka-server.com/facade/users` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Eureka can't proxy your calls through it, it's pure service discovery. But you can add a separate Zuul service with reverse proxy filtering which uses Eureka client to discover routes. Spring Cloud Netflix Zuul component has this out of the box.